# Clojure: # (hash) vs re-pattern

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure, and I discovered that there are two way to create a regular expression:

1. `(re-pattern "12(ab)*34")`
2. `#"12(ab)*34"`

I did a quick benchmark, and it seems that (1) is considerably faster than (2) when using boot repl (took ~7 seconds instead of ~10 seconds when in a loop).

May I ask as to why that may be? I was expecting the #"" syntax to do some clever compile-time optimisation, but instead it's slower than watching paint dry.

Comment: A ‘quick benchmark’, eh? Well, a ‘quick benchmark’ and a ‘meaningful and interesting observation’ are almost mutually exclusive … how are you measuring this? Where is one faster than the other?

Comment: That is to say, when measuring performance methodology is everything. Yes, `#""` does compile to code that should be faster than `re-pattern`, so the difference is almost certainly due to a flawed benchmark.

Comment: Test them using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium/). This will tell you how they compare when the JVM  has settled down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're measuring - you mentioned just construction of regex objects which is probably not what you are interested in.

However, measuring re-find to match string with regex yields quite similar results in both cases

```
(let [re #"12(ab)*34"
      s "aanbciasdfsidufuo12ab34xcnm,xcvnm,xncv,m"]
  (c/quick-bench 
   (re-find re s)))

Evaluation count : 907494 in 6 samples of 151249 calls.
             Execution time mean : 659.120946 ns
...


(let [re (re-pattern "12(ab)*34")
      s "aanbciasdfsidufuo12ab34xcnm,xcvnm,xncv,m"]
  (c/quick-bench 
   (re-find re s)))
Evaluation count : 1018872 in 6 samples of 169812 calls.
             Execution time mean : 588.138157 ns
...
```

There's nothing fundamentally different between literal regex syntax and `re-pattern`. Both end up using `java.util.Pattern.compile` method to compile final regex.

`re-pattern` source code:

```
...
  [s] (if (instance? java.util.regex.Pattern s)
        s
        (. java.util.regex.Pattern (compile s))))
```

literal syntax is handled by [LispReader$RegexReader nested class](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L541):

```
public static class RegexReader extends AFn{
    static StringReader stringrdr = new StringReader();

    public Object invoke(Object reader, Object doublequote, Object opts, Object pendingForms) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ...
        return Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
    }
}
```